# Command to remove semicolon from smb.conf file in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

Could you share the command to delete one line semicolon from smb.conf file.

Eg: i have line as follows `;[homes]` from this i wanted to remove only the `semicolon` at the beginning. So kindly share the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the sed command.

```
sed -i 's#^;\[homes\]#\[homes\]#' smbc.conf
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...! it worked perfectly. Thanks Eden...!